# Any Package for Swarm implementation in ROS..?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is their any specific package for implementation of swarm intelligence for mobile robots using ROS ; As it greatly supports Master(roscore) and multiple Slave (Nodes)paradigm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56724/any-package-for-swarm-implementation-in-ros..?/) by [Cybertron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3895/cybertron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might get an answer if you go through [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/11192/swarm-robotics-facility-in-ros/).

I guess you have misunderstood the concept of ROS_MASTER. It is true that roscore is the master (in robotless scenario) but not in the sense you have understood and other nodes running are not slave nodes. roscore is not a single node, it is a collection of nodes needed to run a ROS system. Master node is the one that keeps track of other nodes, services, topics etc. Read more [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscore) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Master). Of course you can write nodes for swarm robotics where one node acts as a master and others are slaves but relationship between roscore and other nodes is not the proper analogy.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cybertron](https://answers.ros.org/users/3895/cybertron/) on 2013-03-01**:
Thank u ..